# Using double quotes in double quoted string (for sed)

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am adding additional functionality to an install script and decided to edit another file for an upgrade. To accomplish this I will need to get a working sed command using the following on Linux:

```
sed -i "s/TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN="4096M"/TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN="5096M"/g" /tmp/conf/start_tm_console
```

Context sed version details:

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

The issue I have is of course the use of `""` around the values 4096M and 5096M. Not too sure how to complete the sed command have it ignore the additional `""`. Did anyone encounter anything like this?

Actively researching.

Here are my findings, that of course do not work:

```
sed -i "s/TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN=[\"]4096M[\"]/TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN=[\"]5096M[\"]/g" /tmp/conf/start_tm_console

sed -i 's~TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN="4096M"~TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN="5096M"~g' /tmp/conf/start_tm_console
```

EDIT:

Here are some of the contents of this file. This file only has one occurrence of the line mentioned above.

```
#
# This value must be a multiple of 1024 greater than 1MB. Append the letter k or
# K to indicate kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes. The default value is
# 2MB.
#
[ -z "${TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN}" ] && TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN="4096M"

#
# Specify the maximum size, in bytes, of the memory allocation pool. This value
# must a multiple of 1024 greater than 2MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate
# kilobytes, or m or M to indicate megabytes. The default value is 64MB.
#
[ -z "${TM_JAVA_MEM_MAX}" ] && TM_JAVA_MEM_MAX="6144M"
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting. The last `sed` in your post should work - the one using single quotes.

Comment: Not a single error message when I run it. When I cat the file, the values are still the same. Is there a verbose mode in sed? Checking now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the file you are parsing. The last command should work, if it doesn't then your file is probably not as you expect.

Comment: Hey @terdon I have edited the question with the content of the file I am parsing, does this work? Out of the three commands, you believe the last command, of the three, works? I tried this recently, I realized it worked I used cat on the original file in PROD.~~~ sed -i "s/TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN=[\"]4096M[\"]/TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN="5096M"/g" /tmp/conf/start_tm_console
~~~ Well, it does find the 4096M but strips the "". I am working on that one, however, I will try the last command on a clean file.

Comment: The file you posted doesn't contain the expected input: there are no quotes around `5096M` (which is not 4096M, either).

Comment: Hey @choroba thank you for your reply. My apologies, I added the output that was altered. The contents are correct now.

Comment: Ah! The last command does work! @doneal24 - terdon thank you! I think I can also get the regex exp string to work as well. I will play around with it.

Comment: The actual _code_ in the script that you are modifying allows you to set `TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN` as an environment variable.  Setting that with e.g. `export TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN="5096M"` before running the script would have the same effect as actually changing the file, but would not be as intrusive.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!

```
sed -i 's~TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN="4096M"~TM_JAVA_MEM_MIN="5096M"~g' /tmp/conf/start_tm_console
```

I can confirm this does work. I used cat on the original file in production and could not see my changes. ;P!

Comment: Yay! Get used to using single (`'`) and not double `(")` quotes around sed instuctions, by the way. Single quotes protect the contents from the shell which is what you want in 90% of cases. Off the top of my head, you only want double quotes if you i) need to have single quotes inside the sed expression or ii) you want to use a shell variable in your sed expression.

Comment: Thank you @terdon! I had one special case with this expression sed -i "s/innodb_page_size=16M/#innodb_page_size=16M/g". I could not use the single (') due to the = I believe. Would happen to know of any documentation to change the sed express from sed 's/text/newtext/g' vs sed 's~text~oldtext~g'.

Comment: @SwiperNo the use of `=` would not have been impacted by using single quotes

Comment: @SwiperNo the only character you cannot include within since quotes is a single quote. So you cannot do any variation of `'foo\'bar'`, but you can do `'foo'\''bar'` or, less robustly as it'll fail given some other chars in the script, `"foo'bar"`.